# Changing site title server-side

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, title

How can I change a web page title for everyone on that site and **not** to be changed with refreshing, using javascript or PHP?

I've tried **HTML DOM title** but it gets back to its first title after refreshing.

I've tried giving **variable in PHP** and changing it by after a button pressed but the title didn't change!
These were my codes:

```
<?php
    $title = "Chat";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="chat_messages"></div>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <input onClick="dokme()" class="button2" type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
                </form>
    </div>
            <?php
             if(isset($_POST['send'])){
                $title = "new message";
             }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea what should I do?

Comment: You will need to store this value somewhere on the server side, so that you can read it back from there, when you are serving the page to another user. The form data you submit, is unique to you, that has no connection to anyone viewing the site.

Comment: is it your site that you are trying to modify?

Comment: @Professor Of course not I'd simplified whole code

Comment: so essentially you are looking for help in defacing ( not really hacking ) somebody else's site?

Comment: @Professor Come on I'm working on a chatroom.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to help.

Of course the title won't change, because php reads your code from 1st line to the end, and you have already added `$title = "Chat";`

what to do is to change the code like this:

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) $title = "new message";
    else $title = "Chat";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="chat_messages"></div>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <input onClick="dokme()" class="button2" type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
                </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will change the title.

Also, if you want to change the title without refreshing the page, you need JS.

Just use

```js
document.title = '***'; //use your title to replace "***"!
```

Have a good day~

Comment: Thanks but that just change title for me not for every one on the site.

Comment: what does "every one" means??   As a WEB programmer should know, if one can see the change, others can see the change if they use the same browser. You should tell us what problem actaully it is for us to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: I mean title is changed only for browser that user clicks the send button. I want it changed for all browsers on that site.

Comment: oh! i can get it.

Comment: This needs Mysql or Redis. If someone click the button, send a message to the database, and Then use ajax to pull the title back.

Comment: i don't know your database using, so please give more information.

Comment: I don't use database all data's are stored in text files

Comment: well, that means very low efficiency~ anyway, i'll changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

**There are some mistakes in your code like you have used onClick instead you should use onclick**

**you have not putted a semicolon *;* while you are typing**

**You have not assigned action to your form**

**Action will be  echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])**

> And we will use if else

**This will work**

```
<?php



if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $title = "new message";
} else {

    $title = "Chat";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chat_messages"></div>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input onclick="dokme()" class="button2" type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> I hope this will Help you

Comment: Thanks but that just change title for me not for every one on the site.

Comment: What does every one means 

Comment: I mean title is changed only for browser that user clicks the send button. I want it changed for all browsers on that site.

Comment: For that you have to link it to a database